# C# Stack overflow exception when trying to Set in Get

Tags: c#, get, set, stack-overflow

So I'm trying to be smart about this but it looks like this idea is quite dumb on account of I'm getting a stack overflow exception right off the bat.

Ideally, I would like for `CheckInternetStatus` to run whenever I use the `IsConnected` flag.

How can I accomplish this correctly? Or is this just not a good idea at all?

```
public static class Internet
{
    public static bool IsConnected
    {
        get
        {
            CheckInternetStatus();
            return IsConnected;
        }
        set
        {
            IsConnected = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Additional Information: `CheckInternetStatus` updates `IsConnected`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two things wrong with your code:

**1**) No backing variable, you are recursively calling property `IsConnected`:

```
private bool _isConnected;

public static bool IsConnected
{
    get
    {
        _isConnected = CheckInternetStatus();
        return _isConnected;
    }
    set
    {
        _isConnected = value;
    }
}
```

**2**) You should not do 'lots of work' in a property. Use a method instead. This better conveys intent to someone reading your code

Actually 3 things:

**3**) If you stick with using a property (I wouldn't), the setter should probably be `private`. You don't want connected to be set if you are not actually connected.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I voted for yours as it is the most concise and in-depth.

Answer (score 4):

think you want

```
private static bool _isConnected;
public static bool IsConnected
    {
        get
        {
            CheckInternetStatus();
            return _isConnected;
        }
        set
        {
            _isConnected= value;
        }
    }
```

because you are recursively calling into your property

Answer (score 1):

This is a case where a backing field can be extremely useful.

```
private static bool _isConnected;

public static bool IsConnected {
    get {
        CheckInternetStatus();
        return _isConnected;
    }
    set {
        _isConnected= value;
    }
}
```

### Alternatives

> Additional Information: CheckInternetStatus updates IsConnected

`CheckInternetStatus` should manipulate the private field. Futhermore, the `set` should be private (or possibly not exist). But `IsConnected` seems to have a somewhat unexpected side-effect (the act of connecting). Instead, what about:

```
public static bool IsConnected {
    get;
    private set;
}

public static void Connect(){
    if( IsConnected ){
        // exit, or fail if this is considered an exceptional scenario
    }

    // do work
    IsConnected = true;
}

// call
if( !Foo.IsConnected ){
    Foo.Connect();
}
```

This seems cleaner and more obvious. Properties (as a general rule) shouldn't perform large amounts of work.

Comment: Just remember that `CheckInternetStatus()` should be setting `_isConnected` rather than `IsConnected`, too.

Answer (score 0):

You're infinitely recursing.

```
return IsConnected;
```

calls your getter, which calls your getter again and again, infinitely, until you crash.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this wrong. You need some instance variable. You are calling yourself. Correction looks like:

```
public static class Internet
{
private static bool _isConnected;

public static bool IsConnected
{
    get
    {
        CheckInternetStatus();
        return _isConnected;
    }
    set
    {
        _isConnected = value;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also use like this,

```
       private static bool _isConnected;

        public static bool isConnected
        {
            get { CheckInternetStatus(); return _isConnected; }
            set { isConnected = value; }
        }
```

Comment: How is this any different than the half-dozen answers already stating the same thing?

Comment: oops im sorry, i forgot to refresh the page, so I didn't notice that there are already answers, sorry ,

Comment: No problem. You should see a bar across the page saying "new answers to this question", which you can click to see new answers and save answering something that has already been answered.